# How to make my matplotlib rc module preferable parameters as defaults to all my python files?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code at my python scripts

```
from matplotlib import rc

rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
rc('text', usetex=True)

params = {'text.usetex': True,
      'axes.labelsize': 18}`
```

I want to have those preference as defaults when I start a python console instead of copy paste all the time.

Do you know if this is possible?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Customize your matplotlibrc file](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) by adding or uncommenting:

```
font.family         : sans-serif
font.sans-serif     : Helvetica
text.usetex         : True
axes.labelsize      : 18
```

See [ThePredator's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36155979/190597) to find out where your matplotlibrc file is located.

Answer (score 1):

You can see [the webpage for more details](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.rcdefaults)

Use `mpl.matplotlib_fname()` to get your `rc` file path, and modify it according to your manual settings.

```
In [1]: import matplotlib as mpl 

In [2]: mpl.matplotlib_fname()
Out[2]: '/etc/matplotlibrc'
```

In my case the file exists at `/etc/matplotlibrc`